# how to pass image id to javascript page

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass the id of a dynamic image to javascript function but always getting null or [ObjectHTMLElement].

Here is my code:

```
function image_select(id) {  
    document.onmousemove=function(e) {
        var avatar = document.getElementsById(id);
        avatar.style.position='relative';
        avatar.style.left = Math.min(Math.max(e.x-530,-25 ),25)+ "px";
        avatar.style.top = Math.max(Math.min(e.y-256,90),-8) + "px";    
    }
}

function onup(id) {
    document.onmouseup=function() {
        document.getElementById(id).style.position='relative';
        document.onmousemove=null
    }
}


<div id="<?php echo $line4->id."back"; ?>" style="background-image:url(images/fp1.jpg);background-size:100%; padding:0px; margin:0px; background-repeat:no-repeat; border:thin solid black; width:130px; height:130px;" >

    <img name="<?php echo $line->id ?>" src="<?php echo "admin/files/".$line4->image_path3; ?>" 
            style="z-index:1; opacity:.4;" 
            onMouseDown="image_select(<?php echo $line->id ?>);" 
            onMouseUp="onup(<?php echo $line->id ?>);" />
</div>
```

Comment: `$line4->id` I dont think that this id is from javascript, you can't pass javascript stuff to php

Comment: What happens when you actually give an id to the image?

Comment: I dont understand what you want?

Comment: it shows nothing or null when i pass dynamic id of image to javascript function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you'd really need is:

```
onMouseDown="image_select(this);"
```

and

```
function image_select(obj) {
    document.onmousemove=function(e) {
       obj.style.position='relative';
       obj.style.left = Math.min(Math.max(e.x-530,-25 ),25)+ "px";
       obj.style.top = Math.max(Math.min(e.y-256,90),-8) + "px"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx its working ..but little problem is that for various images onmousemove is not in  coordination ...its not going with image what should i do to correct it

Comment: if you awent to be dragging around multiple items, you'd need something more complex, because this could will only ever drag the one item you clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that this:

```
var avatar = document.getElementsByName(id);
```

Isn't supposed to be:

```
var avatar = document.getElementById(id);
```

The `getElementsByName` method will return an HTMLCollection of elements, which you access like so:

```
avatar[0].textContent = "Yay, I'm the first matched item";
```

Comment: actually it was mistake...i also tried passing the name but getting null or nothing

Answer (score 0):

use the

```
     document.getElementById(id)
```

instead of

```
     document.getElementsByName(id)
```

link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: http://w3fools.com/ - Proper source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById